# zfs snapshot send to remote system as a backup file

Tags: zfs, snapshot

I want to send a zfs snapshot to a remote system as a backup file. For example, I've a remote system (Solaris) on a network with a big storage and i want to send rpool and/or zpool snapshots of multiple systems to that one location as backup files. Even better if the snapshot being sent is compressed on the recv remote system. I cannot first compress the snapshot on the source system due to space issue.

What is the command syntax/options to use with zfs recv part?

In the following incomplete command i want to send the "app@fullsnap-9june22" to a remote system as backup file. I do not want the zpool to be created and mounted on the remote system by the sent snapshot

sudo zfs send -R app@fullsnap-9june22 | pv | ssh ip-address zfs recv ???syntax???

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand your question.
If you just want to capture serialized zfs data stream as is, for example onto a tape or onto a huge storage you can just do:

```
# zfs send -R app@fullsnap-9june22 > /big/storage/yousnap.zfs
```

Now the file will contain replayable zfs data stream, once you transfer your storage to location, you mount it and can replay it in same way you captured it:

```
# cat /big/storage/yousnap.zfs | zfs recv ...
```

Any storage is fine even tape. The problem with this method is that you lose redundancy because simple error in the file might breaks it's replayability.

Thats why we send and receive zfs data streams directly to pools, so that replayed stream benefits from storage redundancy in target pool.

Or are you rather asking how to store copies of mutiple nested zfs pools (from multiple machines) within one bigger "concentrator" pool?

Comment: Yes, to your last question. 

I understand the first example you shared. But for that the yousnap.zfs will be created on the same host on which the snapshot was taken. 

If for example, i only have rpool on the host and its space utilization is more than 90%. Then i would want the snapshot backup to be sent and archived on a remote system with enough storage.

Comment: Than that is much more complex question with several issues, that were not yet very ironed out when I started doing it, so my way of doing it might be outdated. I think one most importnat issue is, that you need pretty recent zfs on the "client host"/sender that supports so called "bookmars" (I think) - otherwise you will be unable to delete snapshots on the sender (without bookmarks you need to keep snaphots on the sender too - if I remember correctly). Do you have bookmarks support?